# How to set a cookie to hide a notice bar on second page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

This is what I wan't:

- A new user visits my website. A notice bar fixed to the bottom of the viewport is visible.
- The user then clicks on a menu item, to go to another page. A cookie is set on 2nd page load, that hides the notice bar for 60 days (must be 100% hidden and not flash on page load duo to javascript being loaded asynchronous).
- The user can also click on the "Ok" button to close the notice bar and set the same cookie.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="cookie-message">
    <span>Cookie notice here <a href="#">Read more</a> <a href="#" id="cookie-message-close">Ok</a></span>
</div>
```

How can I do this with jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the cookie have to be set on second page load?  You can drop the cookie on first page load, but since the cookie didn't exist at first, the bar would still show up.  You just would need to ensure the the bar is always hidden at first and only show in the absence of the cookie.  This it would show on first page load and not subsequent page loads.  The cookie you drop should have a 60 day expiration.

Comment: That would work too. I just don't know how to code it, and I can't find similar solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your response, Henrique. However I couldn't get it to work duo to a "jQuery $.cookie is not a function" error.

I found out that "jQuery Cookie" is deprecated and [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) is the new version. By including that and changing the old cookie functions to the new ones it now works perfectly!

This is my final jQuery code, using "js-cookie":

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    jQuery('#cookie-message-close').click(function(){
        jQuery('#cookie-message').hide();
    });

    if (!Cookies.get("cookie-message-bar"))
    {
        jQuery('#cookie-message').show();
        Cookies.set('cookie-message-bar', true, { expires: 60 });
    }
});
```

Note that I've changed $ to jQuery because of Wordpress' noConflict() mode, since I'm developing in Wordpress.

Comment: That is not true. The expires value should be an integer and is counted in days. Check https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: Pardon me. Realised too late that you were using the Cookies object and built-in library.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a API to deal with cookies, makes the things much more easy.

First of all you put `display: none;` in the div cookie-message.

About the logic of hidden or not the notice, you can put a listener in the first load of the window:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){...});
```

this way you can get the moment when the window is loaded. If in this moment there is no cookie for notice read, you show the div (`$('#cookie-message').show()`, and then you set up a cookie. If there is a cookie for that already set, you do nothing.

About the OK click, set up a click listener in the link to hide the notice div (`$('#cookie-message').show()`).

To help you, I make a [simple example](https://codepen.io/henriquebertoldi/pen/WOaRoj) example of what I said.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! With a few adjustments mentioned in the below reply, I managed to fix it. :)

Comment: Remember that you can also check for cookies in PHP and omit rendering the cookie notice altogether if the cookie is set, with a check like `in_array("your-cookie-name", array_keys($_COOKIE))`.